# Need to create two views having same content type and title

Tags: views

I have one content type with the name gallery and uploaded all the images using that content type in different nodes. Now i have two basic pages having views for 2010 and 2011 gallaries.
While i am using views i have differentiated that views using content-title(filter criteria).
Now the problem is the title is same for 2010 and 2011. While i am trying to use one in 2011 gallery using title it is taking from 2010 gallery itself. How to solve this ?

Comment: Are 2010 & 2011 the dates the nodes are created, or you are storing the year in a field.

Comment: Just created basic pages.In that basic page i need to have a view of one content type(the gallery which have the title same).I did not store the year in any field.